# Difference between function and method

Tags: c#, javascript, objective-c, c, oop

What is the difference between function and method ? Can any one say with suitable example say what are the differences? Where we say some routines are called function and where it is called method?

Answer (score 0):

Function or a method is a named callable piece of code which performs some operations and optionally returns a value. 

In **c** language the term function is used. **Java** & **C#** people call these methods (and a function in this case is defined within a class/object).

A C++ programmer might call it a function or sometimes method (depending on if they are writing procedural style c++ code or are doing object oriented way of c++).
You call a function by just calling it's name like `result = mySum(num1, num2);`
You would call a method by referencing its object first like

```
result = MyCalc.mySum(num1,num2);
```

Check the link in CubanAzucy's answer. It is already discussed in great detail on Stack Overflow.